# C# Console, Checking when just enter is entered

Tags: c#

I have a simple if statement

```
string response = Console.Readline();
if ((response[0] >= 97 || response[0] <= 122) && response.Length == 1 && Char.IsLetter(response[0]) && response[0] != 13)
```

I'm looking for input that is between A-Z, and only 1 character long.  Whenever I type just enter into the console, this if statement executes (which is why I thought response[0] != 13 would prevent that).

So using Console.ReadLine(), how can I stop the if statement from executing if just the enter key is used in the console?

Comment: `simple if statement` that so long that it goes off the right side of the screen.

Comment: Check `response.Length` is greater than zero *before* other checks that assume it's at least 1.

Comment: you're indexing in to `reponse`  4 times in a single if statement. you should put it in variable. How is this simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just press enter, "response" will be an empty string

to exclude the empty string from your if statement,  type

```
if(response != "" && ...
```

Comment: Didn't realize the order of the if statements mattered.  This worked. thank you.

Comment: @adrotter  That's a different topic, but yes, the order in the if statement does matter.  If the runtime sees an if statement that looks like `if(false && stuff)`, it won't even attempt to evaluate `stuff` because it already knows the result of the predicate will be `false` no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding, you want to read in as soon as the letter character is pressed and don't want anything to happen when `Enter` is pressed.  If so, use Console.ReadKey() instead:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx